# How can I restrict changes to certain fields in a view for a user?

Tags: views, users

I have a view with a few fields and a few filters. I was wondering if there is a way to restrict a certain role from being able to change the fields/filters but only change one filter?

I know I can restrict access to the whole views from certain roles that's not what i'm trying to accomplish.

Example:
[image]

Edit:
Sorry, should have been more clear.

I have a client who has a service being featured on the front page of the site.

I have a view which shows fields from the featured service content type.

I need the owner of the site to be able to filter which piece of content to be show on the front of the site with the filter that should be editable but not mess up the view by accidentally changing other fields or filters. I do not need the filter exposed to visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose only the `Title` filter to the user. They will be able to see all of the content, but only specify the exposed filter.

You can expose a filter while editing it by checking the box that says "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it".

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. I have a client who has a service being featured on the front page of the site. I have a view which shows fields from the featured service content type. I need the owner of the site to be able to filter which piece of content to be show on the front of the site with the filter that should be editable but not mess up the view by accidentally changing other fields or filters. I do not need the filter exposed to visitors.

Comment: Will they just be using that filter to determine which pieces of content show up on the homepage? If so, I would recommend that you implement draggable views or entity queue along with a limited number of items to display the content.

Comment: The Views Admin UI does not have support for fine-grained access based on user Role. as @lukedekker mentions it's better to expose a `nodequeue` or `entityqueue` to the enduser -- and have the View you setup reference the list of usable nodes.

Comment: Thanks, this is a lot more user friendly for potential users too!